# AWS - EC2 : How to use a different public address for outbound connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have an AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance with an elastic IP address assigned to it and running a web application.

I would like to run a web scraping script on my server and I do not prefer my server / domain to be back-traced from the IP address my script connects to external websites.

For this purpose I decided to enable and use a NAT gateway on the VPC. However when I changed the default route on the VPC towards NAT gateway, I have also lost connection to my own server.

Here I will appreciate if you can guide me to create a solution via NAT gateway or by some other way?

EDIT:
I am trying to implement an information aggregation app and I am quite confident that my script do not violate any term of use and  for this reason I am planning to use a NAT gateway configured with a static IP (which is back-traceable). Moreover I know the possible implications on the server load hence by I never create any problem by limiting queries.

Comment: *"I do not prefer my server / domain to be back-traced from the IP address my script connects to external websites."*  That description makes it sound like you are doing something that you know you should not be doing, and your motivation is not getting caught, not having your site identified as being responsible for violating another site's terms of use.  If this is true, then I would suggest that asking the question here is not appropriate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think it's appropriate for Server Fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As *@Michael - sqlbot* says if you’re trying to do something you shouldn’t be doing - don’t do it.
2. NAT Gateway IP is still traceable back to you. It won’t help make you anonymous.

Comment: Indeed. If someone's web scraper causes a problem to my server, I'll just email the logs to Amazon abuse and Amazon will yell at them for me. Or maybe just kick them off the platform entirely.